# Why does my Flycheck syntax checker not activate automatically?

Tags: flycheck

I wrote [a Flycheck frontend](https://notabug.org/koz.ross/flycheck-ldc/src/master/flycheck-ldc.el) for [LDC](http://wiki.dlang.org/LDC). It installs into Emacs fine, and I remember to `require` it, but for some reason, it doesn't automatically enable itself when I open a file in `d-mode`. What did I miss?

**Edit:** As per request, here are the relevant parts of my init file:

```
;;D
(autoload 'd-mode "d-mode" "Major mode for editing D code." t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.d[i]?\\'" . d-mode))

;;Flycheck
(require 'flycheck-ldc)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
(setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers '(c/c++-clang))
```

**Edit 2:** As per request, here is the result of `C-c ! v` in a `d-mode` buffer:

```
Syntax checkers for buffer logic.d in d-mode:

  d-dmd
    - predicate:  nil
    - executable: Not found

Flycheck Mode is enabled.

The following syntax checkers are not registered:

  - d-ldc

 Try adding these syntax checkers to `flycheck-checkers'.
```

Comment: That's impossible to say with as little information as you have given. Please edit your question and add the relevant parts of your init file.  Specifically, show your D-Mode and Flycheck setup.

Comment: I have some foggy memory that flycheck keeps a list of major modes where it should be enabled. Don't remember what the variable name. You would probably find it if you looked into its sources.

Comment: Do you actually turn flycheck on in your `d-mode` buffers?  For instance, automatically with `(add-hook 'd-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)`

Comment: I just noticed that you enable `global-flycheck-mode`, so my suggestion in the previous comment should not be necessary.

Comment: - What does the function `flycheck-possibly-suitable-checkers` return when run in your D buffer?
- Is `flycheck-mode` `t` in your D buffer?
- What does `flycheck-may-enable-mode` return in your D buffer?
- Why not add `d-dmd` to `flycheck-disabled-checkers`?

Comment: Please type `C-c ! v` in a D Mode buffer, and add the contents of the buffer which pops up to your question.  Feel free to use a screenshot if that's convenient for you.

Comment: @lunaryorn Added per your request.

Answer (score 3):

Flycheck does not find syntax checkers automagically.  It's not enough to just define a syntax checker, you also need to *register* it, by adding it to `flycheck-checkers`, as Flycheck told you.

```
(add-to-list 'flycheck-checkers 'd-ldc)
```

For more information please consult the  Flycheck manual which guides you through the whole process of [defining a new syntax checker](http://www.flycheck.org/manual/latest/Syntax-checker-definitions.html%23Syntax-checker-definitions).

Comment: My source clearly indicates that I do exactly this (line 62 to be exact).

Comment: I'm sorry, but the output clearly indicates that you did *not* successfully register the checker.  Flycheck doesn't lie—there must be something wrong in your code.  Did you check for possible typos?

Answer (score 1):

For `malabar-mode`, which is enabled in java and groovy buffers,  I also added:

```
(flycheck-define-generic-checker 'jvm-mode-malabar
  "Integrate flycheck with the malabar JVM service."
  :start #'malabar-flycheck-command
  :modes '(java-mode groovy-mode)
)

(add-to-list 'flycheck-checkers 'jvm-mode-malabar)
```